# MySQL partial select (performance issue)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with more than 300,000 rows (Total table size is 600mb+).

The rows on the table are records of events and each has a time stamp (epoch).

To perform a query on NOT expired events I have to use `WHERE epoch > currentepoch`, but it takes like 5-8 seconds to perform this kind of query. (In fact the number of NOT expired events are no more than 6,000)

So for a simple count of NOT expired events my query takes 5-8 seconds.

Is there any solutions to this? Can I query a part of the table? (Like ignoring the expired events and having MySQL not go trough them at all)

Note: Engine is MyISAM

Note2: I cannot normalize the table as the info are stuff like descriptions etc.

TLDR; Counting 6,000 rows out of a table of 300,000 rows takes 5-8 seconds, solutions?

Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks everyone. After adding an Index the query runs in less than half a second. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you got an index on the epoch column?

Comment: Do both these `epoch` and `currentepoch` are fields of the table?

Comment: Are the fields MySQL date(time) types and do they have an combined index? Post the CREATE TABLE statement and your query please.

Comment: If only `epoch` is a field, do you have an index on it?

Comment: http://www.ajaxline.com/32-tips-to-speed-up-your-mysql-queries will also probably be useful to you

Comment: Follow Wesley's advice. Also post the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...(your query)`

Comment: @BenSwinburne No I dont have an Index on that

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp the table is just a simple table with bunch of fields, the epoch on table is integer(11)

Comment: @ypercube Only the expiry epoch is on the table, then its compared to the current epoch sent by PHP

Comment: Add an index then, on `epoch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a thing called [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) for this purpose

```
CREATE INDEX epoch ON tablename (epoch)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it's not obvious from all the other answers yet, you should create a B-tree [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html) on the `epoch` column.

Also, if you're not yet familiar with [using `EXPLAIN` to study the efficiency of your queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execution-plan-information.html), you should be.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a wise idea to apply [indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on columns that are used in `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, use index on the currentepoch. It allows the table to search through that column faster.

An other solution would be to mark events as expired through a cronjob, updating all expired events with a value, run it each minute and just search on this value instead of using `>`.

Answer (score -1):

You basically should create individual indexes for all the table fields you are searching on your WHERE clause. Combined indexes (with more than one field) should be used in more complex queries but bear in mind that indexes consume database space and resources.

I'm not sure that you can create indexes on myISAM tables - I'm not very knowledgable on MySQL as I prefer real databases ;-) - but if you can't then you should convert the table in question to InnoDB format and then create the indexes you need.

BTW, you mention that your table is not normalizable - that cannot be right, every table is normalizable to some degree depending on the amount of time/effort you want to put into it.
Sometimes, as data grows bigger that is the only way to go, but 300000 rows isn't much really.

Good luck with your efforts!

Comment: OMG, `I'm not sure that you can create indexes on myISAM tables`

Comment: I prefer surreal databases :)

Comment: I wondered too if [I]ndexed [S]equential [A]ccess [M]ethod files were [I]ndexed ;P